# double text when using label with boxes in gnuplot (cairolatex)

Tags: latex, gnuplot

I am trying to use gnuplot with cairolatex as output along with a boxed label. Without the box around the label, the output is fine. However, as soon as I put in box around the label, the text appears twice slightly offset from each other. MWE is as follows:

```
reset session

set terminal cairolatex pdf color standalone font ',9'
set output "erfx.tex"

set key box bottom spacing 1.4

set zeroaxis
set xrange [-3:3]
set yrange [-1:1]

textstr = '$\displaystyle' \
      . '\textrm{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}' \
      . '\int_0^x\, e^{-t^2} \, dt$'

set style textbox 1 opaque fillcolor "white" border linecolor "black" \
    margins 2,2
# Without "boxed bs 1" it works fine, but without the surrounding box
set label 1 textstr at graph 0.05, 0.9 left \
    boxed bs 1

set xlabel '$x \rightarrow$'
set ylabel '$\textrm{erf}(x) \rightarrow$'

plot erf(x) title 'erf$(x)$'

unset output
unset terminal
```

I then use the commands to get the output

```
gnuplot erfx.plt && pdflatex -interaction=batchmode erfx.tex
```

The result is as follows:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from this command

```
set style textbox 1 opaque
```

Gnuplot implements the "opaque box" property by drawing the content once, using that to determine the exact area covered, drawing a solid rectangle that fills the determined area, and then finally writing the text again so that it shows up on top of the solid-fill rectangle.

Unfortunately that sequence doesn't work for the {eps/ps/pdf}latex terminals, because they collect all the text output into a separate layer for LaTeX to render.  So both the pre- and post- rectangle text gets sent to LaTeX.

Your label should work as expected if you switch that to

```
set style textbox 1 transparent
```

The program could probably be smarter about this, but that's what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed a very strange behaviour.
This is not a real solution, but my observations: (maybe somebody else can draw the right conclusions).

- I can reproduce your result if I (freshly) start a gnuplot console, load your script and run `pdflatex` from the operating system console (in my case Windows).
- However, if I load your script a second time from the same open gnuplot console and run `pdflatex`, I don't see this double textbox in the final PDF anymore.

So, probably something must be wrong with some initial gnuplot settings for the cairolatex terminal and/or the textbox.

- If I look at the .tex file (the one where the label appears only **once**), in the `.tex` code your label appears **twice**. I am not sure, if this should be like that.

```
...
     \settowidth{\gptboxwidth}{\widthof{$\displaystyle\textrm{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x\, e^{-t^2} \, dt$}}
    \advance\gptboxwidth by 4\fboxsep
      \savebox{\gptboxtext}{\parbox[c][\totalheight+4\fboxsep]{\gptboxwidth}{\centering{$\displaystyle\textrm{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x\, e^{-t^2} \, dt$}}}
        \definecolor{tbcol}{rgb}{1.00,1.00,1.00}
    \put(1064,3777){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\colorbox{tbcol}{\usebox{\gptboxtext}}}}
      \csname LTb\endcsname%%
      \settowidth{\gptboxwidth}{\widthof{$\displaystyle\textrm{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x\, e^{-t^2} \, dt$}}
    \advance\gptboxwidth by 4\fboxsep
      \savebox{\gptboxtext}{\parbox[c][\totalheight+4\fboxsep]{\gptboxwidth}{\centering{$\displaystyle\textrm{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x\, e^{-t^2} \, dt$}}}
    \settowidth{\gptboxwidth}{\usebox{\gptboxtext}}
    \advance\gptboxwidth by 2\fboxsep
    \put(1064,3777){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\framebox[\gptboxwidth]{\usebox{\gptboxtext}}}}
...
```

So, a not very satisfying solution would be to **add** the following lines at the end of your script:

```
set output "erfx.tex"
replot
set output
system('pdflatex erfx.tex')
```

With this, loading the script from the gnuplot console, I get a single textbox all the time.